# Highcharts live chart shifts continuously

Tags: highcharts

I have the following issue:

I initialize the chart with null values because I don't have meaningful initial values.
I add points with addPoint after getting the data through ajax
The problem is that the chart shifts continuously and not just on the end of the time range.

I use the code:

```
generateInitialData = function() {
        var initialData = [];
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        var i;
        for (i = -99; i <= 0; i++) {
            initialData.push([time + i * 3000,null]);
        }
        return initialData;
    }

addPoint = function(){
    var max = 1000;
    var min = 300;
    var value =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    chart.series[0].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), value], true, true);
}

$('#container').highcharts({
         chart: {
                 type: 'line',
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minRange:1000 * 60 * 5,
                maxRange:1000 * 60 * 5
            }
});

var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

chart.addSeries({"name": "example","data":generateInitialData()});

setInterval(addPoint,3000);
```

Please see jsFiddle demo of the issue :

http://jsfiddle.net/wXmLQ/7/

Please help

Tali

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set null data from the beginning, instead of that you can just addd one empty point and just check if you want to shift or not, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/wXmLQ/8/

```
addPoint = function(){
  var max = 1000;
  var min = 300;
  var value =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  var len = chart.series[0].data.length;
  chart.series[0].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), value], len < 99);
}

$('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
             type: 'line',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minTickInterval: 1000 * 60, //one minute
            minRange:1000 * 60 * 5,
            maxRange:1000 * 60 * 5
        }
});

var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

chart.addSeries({"name": "example","data":[[+new Date(), null]]});

setInterval(addPoint,3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The addPoint and addSeries methods have a re-draw parameter that defaults to true. Make this parameter false whenever you call an updating method

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), value], false);
chart.addSeries({"name": "example","data":generateInitialData()}, false);
```

Then once you've made all the updates, explicitly redraw the chart

```
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: But I need the update to be visible for each addPoint (which I do every 3 seconds) I just don't want the shift

Comment: The third parameter for addPoint is a boolean for the shift, the default is false, so either leave it off, or explicitly pass "false". Right now you are passing true.

Comment: I need the shift. I only want to show 5 minutes. I initialized the chart with all the points for the 5 minutes. If i will put false for shift the chart x Axis time range will grow and the graph will be more "condensed".

Comment: To be more exact - the shift works for me on the xAxis - the range stays 5 minutes and does not grow. But on the y Axis the point is shifted with the end of the visible part of the line instead of the left most point of the graph.